# Разместить элементы футера, как на скрине?

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Необходимо разместить элементы футера, как на скрине. У меня все время что-то где-то неровно...

```css
.footer {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    padding: 58px 0 130px 0;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background: #2C2C2C;
    line-height: 24px;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.footerLogoLink {
    display: block;
}

.navFooterLink {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.navFooterSectionTitle {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 0 25px 0;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.footerItemLink,
.contactsItem {
    margin: 0 0 16px 0;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.contacts {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    max-width: 320px;
}

.contactsItem {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 0 0 30px;
}

.contactsItem::before {
    position: absolute;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    display: block;
    content: '';
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    background-size: 16px 16px;
}

.addressIcon::before {
    background: url("../img/footer/maps.png") no-repeat;
}

.phoneIcon::before {
    background: url("../img/footer/phone-call.png") no-repeat;
}

.emailIcon::before {
    background: url("../img/footer/email.png") no-repeat;
}

.social {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between; 
    text-decoration: none;
}

.facebook,
.google,
.linkedin,
.twitter {
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    background: url("../img/social/facebook.png") no-repeat;
    background-size: 16px 16px;
    text-indent: -10000px;
}

.linkedin {
    background: url("../img/social/linkedin.png") no-repeat;
}

.twitter {
    background: url("../img/social/twitter.png") no-repeat;
}

.google {
    background: url("../img/social/google-plus.png") no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<footer class="footer">
    <a class="footerLogoLink" href="#">
        <img class="footerImage" src="img/footerLogo.png">
    </a>
    <nav class="navFooterLink">
        <div class="navFooterSectionTitle">Информация</div>
        <a class="footerItemLink" href="#">Главная</a>
        <a class="footerItemLink" href="#">Галерея</a>
        <a class="footerItemLink" href="#">Проекты</a>
        <a class="footerItemLink" href="#">Сертификаты</a>
        <a class="footerItemLink" href="#">Контакты</a>
    </nav>
    <div class="contacts">
        <div class="navFooterSectionTitle">Контакты</div>
        <div class="contactsItem addressIcon">
            100000, Реуспублика Казахстан.
            г. Караганда, ул. Телевизионная, 10
        </div>
        <div class="contactsItem phoneIcon">
            +7(701)77 76 811 
        </div>
        <div class="contactsItem emailIcon">
            Galym.sultanov@mail.ru
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="social">
        <div class="navFooterSectionTitle">Социльаные сети</div>
        <a class="facebook" href="#">
            Facebook
        </a>
        <a class="twitter" href="#">
            Twitter
        </a>
        <a class="linkedin" href="#">
            Linkedin
        </a>
        <a class="google" href="#">
            Google Plus
        </a>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Может свой css добавите?

Comment: Надо div сделать и в него включить другие div'ы, для внутренних один класс, для внешнего другой класс в CSS. Какой-нибудь alignment поставить в нужное свойство у контейнера-div и будут в столбик отображаться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно, как-то так:

```css
footer {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 40px;
  background-color: white;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

footer>div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <footer class="">
    <div style="width:25%; border: solid 1px;">
      left element
    </div>
    <div style="width:25%; border: solid 1px;">
      center
    </div>
    <div style="width:25%; border: solid 1px;">
      element
    </div>
    <div style="width:25%; border: solid 1px;">
      right element
    </div>
</body>
```

сурс: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59244406/6897369